# DVD-RW does not read regular CDS/DVDs on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, dvd, hardware-failure

I have a dell vostro 1510 laptop with windows vista.

It has an "Optiarc DVD+-RW AD-7640A ATA Device" installed which used to work find.

My vista has two user profiles on it.

Now when I insert a "normal" (factory burned) CD or DVD into the drive:

- When The first user profile is active: It waits a few seconds then eject the media automatically.
- When the second user profile is active: The icon in the windows explorer for that drive changes from "DVD ROM" to "CD ROM" and nothing else happens until I right click (E:)  and choose explore. It then ejects the CD and pops a dialog with the caption `"Insert a Disk"` which says `"Pleasa Insert a Disk. Please Insert a disk into drive E:"`.

If I insert a blank burning media:

- When The first user profile is active: It pops up the AutoPlay dialog asking if what software do I want to use to burn a DVD with.
- When the second user profile is active: It pops ud a dialog asking me to name the new DVD beig burned"

It feels to me as if the machine somehow thinks its in the middle of a burning process but I don't know how to stop it. (I could be wrong though).

I am Looking for ideas on how I can make it read CDs again.

Comment: Since you added the tag hardware-failure: Why didn't you mention anything about a possible hardware fault in your question? You should check if such a fault is likely by trying it with another OS, e. g. a Linux live system like Knoppix booted from a pen drive or your drive in question.

Comment: Maybe my tagging was wrong in this case. As I indicated I believe this to be a software issue and was hoping that its description would yield software related solutions. If I will get no such suggestions I will try to check the hardware as You suggest.